# Unity create sqlite with android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an sqlite db in android, but when I try this in my phone never create the db...

```
static void obrirConn () {

        dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection ("URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Timmy_Game.db");

        dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
        dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();

        dbcmd.CommandText = "create table IF NOT EXISTS `nivells` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, `temps` INTEGER, `puntuacio` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: You aren't creating a db you are trying to connect to one, that's why it is called SqliteConnection,

Comment: But if I try this in Windows it works fine, how can I create the db with android?

Comment: you probably already have a db on your windows machine. Try searching for 'Create SQLite database' and you will find your answer. Or look up what `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("")` does.

Comment: In windows it create the db, I don't have one but the lane is different.

I have added this line:
SqliteConnection.CreateFile ("URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Timmy_Game.db");

But still don't work...